# Unable to fetch data from CoreData using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, swiftui, core-data

To begin with, the main purpose of using the CoreData in the app is to save the data for the flashcards. However, when I'm trying to try out to print that data the project crashes. I feel like the main problem is that I'm saving the data using dataController and its add() function, however, I'm running ForEach loop into another array - TermAndDefinition.
Here's the code for the dataController where I control the data:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData")
    @Published var savedFlash: [FlashCardData] = []
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    
        }
       
    }
   func fetchRequest() {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData>(entityName: "FlashCardData")
            do {
                savedFlash = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
            } catch let error {
                print("Error fetching... \(error)")
            }
        }
    
    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Data saved")
            fetchRequest()
        } catch {
            print("We could not save the data...")
        }
    }
    func add(term: String, name: String, definition: String, tag: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let data = FlashCardData(context: context)
        data.name = name
        data.id = UUID()
        data.definition = definition
        data.term = term
        data.tag = tag
        save(context: context)
    }
```

Here's the view where the user enters the data and saves it, here, I'm trying to test and print out the data as it appears using ForEach(flaschard), however, I have received an error when the app runs: Thread 1: "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.":

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import CoreData

// ViewModel for managing flashcards

struct TermDefinitionView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: FlashCardData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) private var flashcard: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TermDefinitionViewModel()
    @State var name = "" // Separate state for the name
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var showSet = false
    @Binding var saveSet: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Name")
                        .padding(.trailing, 220)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    TextField("Enter name", text: $name)
                        .frame(width: 250)
                        .padding()
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModel.termdefpairs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            TermView(term: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].term, definition: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].definition, tag: $viewModel.termdefpairs[index].tag)
                        }
                        .onDelete { index in
                            self.viewModel.termdefpairs.remove(at: index.first!)
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                      //  guard !name.isEmpty else { return }
                        saveSet.toggle()
                        for testForm in viewModel.termdefpairs {
                            dataController.add(term: testForm.term, name: name, definition: testForm.definition, tag: testForm.tag, context: managedObjectContext)
                        }
                        dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                    })
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.addNew()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            
                ForEach(flashcard) { entity in
                    Text(entity.name ?? "")
                    Text(entity.term ?? "")
                    Text(entity.definition ?? "")
                    Text(entity.tag ?? "")
                }
            
        }
         
        
    }
}


struct TermDefinitionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TermDefinitionView(saveSet: .constant(true))
    }
}

struct TermView: View {
    @Binding var term: String
    @Binding var definition: String
    @Binding var tag: String
    @State private var isTagExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            
            
                if isTagExpanded {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                        Text("Tag")
                            .font(.headline)
                        TextField("Enter tag", text: $tag)
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    }
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    isTagExpanded.toggle()
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: isTagExpanded ? "minus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        Text(isTagExpanded ? "Hide Tag" : "Add Tag")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, -25)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Term")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("Enter term", text: $term)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text("Definition")
                    .font(.headline)
                TextField("Enter definition", text: $definition)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct TermAndDefinition: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var term: String
    var definition: String
    var tag: String
    
    
}
```

Lastly, in ForEach loop which viewModel.termdefpairs, my assumptions of potential error is that I'm referring to them when displaying TextFields. Here's the ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import CoreData

final class TermDefinitionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var termdefpairs: [TermAndDefinition] = [TermAndDefinition(term: "", definition: "", tag: "")]
    
    private var dataController = DataController()

    func addNew() {
        termdefpairs.append(TermAndDefinition(term: "", definition: "", tag: ""))
    }
```

Comment: When you do `dataController = DataController()` in your view model then you are creating a new core data container meaning the view model will use a different storage than other parts of the application which can lead to errors like the one you get. In how many other places do you create new DataController objects? You are using EnvironmentObject which is one correct way to do it but then you should only use it that way or make DataController a shared object.

Comment: I'm using dataController = DataController() in SetView() - it's a view where I want to  use fetchRequest to fetch the data, TermDefinitionView() - view where user enters the data, NewHomeView() - home view.

Comment: You shouldn't use `DataController()` anywhere other than when create the DataController environmentObject.

Comment: but what if I make DataController.shared?

Comment: That's another good solution, I don't think you need to use it as an environment object then.

Comment: yeah, I have tried to do it with shared and it works, thank you